# cannot resolve symbol while importing constraintlayout in android studio 3.4.2

Tags: android

I am beginner in android and creating a program, whole thing is done but when importing constraintlayout with the importing statement 'import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout' code editor highlighed red and shows 'cannot resolve symbol'.

Comment: are you using androidX?

Comment: Have you added the dependency of constraint layout in your app level's gradle file ?

Comment: How to use androidx don't know about this..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using androidx or use thee version 28.0.0-alpha1 of support library

Comment: I don't know about androidx, how to use it?

Comment: There is a good documentation at android developers official page : 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

- Refactor and migrate your code to Android X.
- Then add this in your `build.gradle` file app level.

> `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

- Sync changes to the project.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to guess what the problem is without a code snippet or screenshot of how you're using constraint layout in your XML but I imagine this Gradle issue is caused you have not imported constraint layout to your build.gradle file. Make sure this is in your build.gradle file in the dependencies section:

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The importing statment is as ...

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;